# Cancel button instead of edit button in address book

Tags: iphone-sdk-4.3

i have added a contact into the address book, i want a cancel button instead of edit button in address book.

how can make it programmatically without using `ABUnknownPersonViewController`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

use `rightbarbutton` and implement `rightbarbuttonitem` in protocol